# Ruby on Rails 3, syntax error while creating a new object

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am still learning Ruby, and still copy pasting from my manual. But I run on a problem, that I dont know how to explain and what am I doing wrong. So here it is:
I want to create a new object with this:

```
second_page = Page.new ( :name=>"Second page", :position=>1, :permalink => "second" )
```

and I got a error:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.10)
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > second_page = Page.new ( :name=>"Second page", :position=>1, :permalink => "second" )
SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting ')'
...econd_page = Page.new ( :name=>"Second page", :position=>1, ...
...                               ^
(irb):1: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting $end
...age.new ( :name=>"Second page", :position=>1, :permalink => ...
...                               ^
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

but, if I do this:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 > second_page = Page.new  :name=>"Second page", :position=>1, :permalink => "second"
 => #<Page id: nil, subject_id: nil, name: "Second page", permalink: "second", position: 1, visible: false, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

that seems to work.
I got example from manual, and I am wondering what is going on?
And without () I dont know how can I do stuff with that object?
Thank you

Comment: Did you try removing the space between `new` and `(`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby doesn't allow you to put spaces before round brackets if you choose to place them. This should work:

```
second_page = Page.new( :name=>"Second page", :position=>1, :permalink => "second" )
```

Comment: Thank you...I cant believe that was the problem...You dont want to know how many times I tried to write this again and again... But I suppose this is learning :)

Comment: It does allow it. But it discourages it and thus emits are warning. But it's not an error, more an issue of style.

Comment: It is a syntax error, not warning. Actually, I didn't know that this works when there is only one ambiguous argument. But I don't see any reason to do that.

Comment: In this case, it's a syntax error because it's ambiguous (although Ruby 1.8 used to interpret it just fine and just emit a warning). But if you resolve the ambiguity you are free to have a space before the parentheses. Not that you should do it, but you can...

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is the parser trying to resolve syntax ambiguities. `Page.new` accepts a single argument: a hash containing attributes which should be set on the newly created active record object.

If you now call the method without any parentheses, it is not initially clear what the arguments are. Thus the parser is smart enough to figure out it should be a hash in this case.

If you actually write the parentheses, you have to be a bit more specific and have to actually write down the hash braces too. Thus the following statements are equivalent:

```
first_page = Page.new :foo => "Bar"
second_page = Page.new({:foo => "Bar"})
third_page = Page.new ({:foo => "Bar"})
```

In most cases, parentheses are optional in method calls in Ruby. But only if there aren't any ambiguities. If in doubt, always specify the parentheses. Note that Ruby 1.9 changed the syntax here and is thus a bit more strict.

Answer (score 1):

In ruby parenthesis to the method arguments are not necessary. So,

```
 object.method()
 # is same as
 object.method

 object.method(param1, param2)
 # is same as 
 object.method param1, param2
```

There is another popular syntax for passing arbitrary number of parameters:

```
def print_a(*params)
  puts params.inspect
end

print_a "a"                                  
#prints: ["a"]

print_a "a", "b"                             
#prints: ["a", "b"]

print_a "a", "b", 2, :four => 4              
#prints: ["a", "b", 2, {:four=>4}]

print_a "a", "b", 3, :four => 4, :five => 5  
#prints: ["a", "b", 3, {:four=>4, :five=>5}]
```

As you may have noticed in the last example ruby is smart enough to detect hashes and aggregate the key value pairs in a single hash argument. But it only works if the hash is last argument.

```
 print_a("a", "b", :four => 4, :five => 5, 3)
 # gives error: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting tASSOC

 # converting the hash to an explicit hash works again
 print_a "a", "b", {:four => 4, :five => 5}, 3
 # ["a", "b", {:four=>4, :five=>5}, 3]
```